# Temporary machine packet best practice

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

i'am trying to setup a good patern for managing and distributing incoming data packet from autonomous machines.

The idea, is to have 1000+ machines, sending data packets (less than 1 ko every 5 sec) to a lambda server that will store in an dynamo-db, i will use it like a, incoming buffer.

This dynamodb will be consumed by another service that will decode the search key of the packet to store it in a postgresql db for further use and packet routing to different bussiness services that will completely decode the packet depeding their type.

What i am thinking :

1. Machine sends the packet to the lambda with machine-sn, priority of the packet (0 to 3), timestamp of the packet, packet-id, and the data. Fyi The machine stores the packet and try back to send it later if connection is broken.
2. Lambda stores PK : machine-sn ; SK a composite key : priority-timestamp-packetid ; raw packet
3. Another service reads with a scanindexforward false to retrieve packets by prio 0 and timestamp, and stores it in a postgresql db in a single table [pk-uuid, ts, sn, prio, packet_ts, packet-type, raw packet, service_1_forwarded(false), service_2_forwarded(false)]. When transaction is commited successfully, we delete stored packets from the dynamodb. and so on for other prios with a timeout if this takes too long, we accept delaying lowers priority packet.
4. Another services, read the table with service_N_forwarded = false, and fully decode the packet and stores it in a dedicated business db for further usage.

Main advantages i see :

- We lean on Amazon scalable service for managing incoming data.
- We can deploy another forwarder service if we have to many timeouts.
- Simple to dev and maintain.
- the system is packet agnostic until it reach a business db that will truely decode data, i can deploy new release of embedded software, and use data later with a dedicated service, meanwhile no data is lost.

Questions I have :

- Is this a sustainable pattern ?
- What should be a smart way to create PK/SK for the dynamodb.
- I know IoT system provided by Amazon, but i prefer internalize this part, for a smooth start, good idea ?
- Can i restrict incoming connection from a vpn with lamba service ? (machines can send data through a vpn).

Thank you for your comments :)

Have a nice day !

Comment: This is a job description for a consulting engagement and not something that lends itself towards the Q&A format of stackoverflow. It's broad, contains multiple questions and I'd argue it's also opinion-based. Voting to close it. Please check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what questions are on topic.

Comment: This is too broad of a question so not going to try to answer the whole thing, but consider taking a look at AWS Kinesis + Firehose, which is designed to do precisely this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.